# Conditional Probability Question for A Continuos Random Variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, conditional-expectation

Suppose $X$ is a continuous random variable with density $p$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure. According to Radon-Nikodym theorem $p$ is measurable itself so it can be seen as a random variable. Question is what is the following expression equal to
$$p(X=x_0|p(X=x_0)=3)\overset{?}{=}3$$
Or in a more general but vaguer sense
$$p\Big(X=x_0\Big|p(X=x)\ {\rm is\ given\ and\ is\ }f(x)\Big)\overset{?}{=}f(x_0)$$
I have guessed what they need to be equal to --after the question marks-- but I do not have any rigour argument to justify them. So I would really appreciate if you could please guide me how to do it (or prove me wrong).

Comment: "$p$ is measurable itself so it can be seen as a random variable." I don't think this is correct. It is a function on the measurable space $\mathbb{R}$ with the Lebesgue measure, but this measurable space is not a probability space. Further, in order for you to make sense of the conditional probabilities you have written, your "random variables" $X$ and $p$ need to live on the same probability space.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. $p$ is measurable and integrates to $1$ over $\Omega$ (the original state space) so I don't see which assumption about being a random variable doens't hold about it? Again I do think they live in the same probability space. Regarding your second comment I don't see why then the following is a correct statement: Suppose $X\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu, 1)$. The quantity of $p(X=x|E[X]=x_0)$ is meaningful and so should be the quantity of what I asked, right?

Comment: The expression you are conditioning on, "$p(X=x_0)=3$", makes no sense to me. $p(X=x_0)$ is a deterministic number, given by the value of the density function at $x_0$. The statement "$p(X=x_0)=3$" is therefore either true or false. You are conditioning on an event which is either empty (which is nonsense) or which is the whole space (which is trivial). Can you clarify what you mean? Did you mean to say "$p(X)=3$, which means you take the random value of $X$ and plug it into the density function, and condition on this random output being 3?

Comment: @MikeEarnest I don't understand why you say that. Take for example $X$ coming from a discrete distribution which is dirac delta function and assume the functions peak (where $p(X=\theta)=1)$ is the parameter to be learned (say $\theta$). Now what is the difference between my question and the question such as $p(X=2|\theta=1)$. Can you tell me why do you find a difference between these two settings?

Comment: I can think of two interpretation of the notation $p(X=x_0|\dots)$. (i) If $X,Y$ are jointly continuous, then $p(X=x_0|Y=y_0)$ is the conditional distribution of $X$ given $Y=y_0$. (ii) If $(X_\theta)_{\theta\in \Theta}$ is a family of distributions parameterized by $\theta$, then $p(X=x_0|\theta=\theta_0)$ is the distribution corresponding to $\theta_0$. It seems like your post uses (i) (since you do not mention a parameter family), while your comment uses (ii). That is the difference.

Comment: @MikeEarnest, thank you for your reply. I guess I have too many doubts about what exactly is what but I try to explain what I mean. I agree with you that I mix these two in a way but I have reasons for it. After all a parametric family in many cases is nothing but a function of the distribution. For example for a Gaussian $(\mu, \sigma)$ are $E(X)$ and $E(X^2)-E(X)^2$. So when the parameter is given it is equivalent to say that the first two moments are given. I am trying to carry the same reasoning to density (or pmf). Where the values of density at some points are given.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p_{\small X}(x)$ be the probability density for the continuously distributed random variable $X$.   Then $p_{\small X}(X)$ is a random variable, and you seem to want to talk about the condtional measure $p_{\small X\mid p_{\small X}(X)=3}(x)$.

The nature of the conditional measure, and whether it even exists, entirely depends on the distribution for the random variable.

- If $X$ has a probability density of $3$ in an integrateable interval of uncountable many points, say $A$, then the conditional probability measure $p_{X\mid X\in A}(x)$ will be a *probability density function*. $$p_{\small X\mid X\in A}(x)=\dfrac{p_{\small X}(x)\mathbf 1_{x\in A}}{\int_A p_{\small X}(s)\mathsf d s}=\dfrac {\mathbf 1_{x\in A}}{\int_A \mathsf d s}$$
- If $X$ has a probability density of $3$ in an interval of finite many points, say $B$, then the conditional probability measure $p_{X\mid X\in B}(x)$ will be a *probability mass function*.
  $$p_{\small X\mid X\in A}(x)=\dfrac{p_{\small X}(x)\mathbf 1_{x\in B}}{\sum_{x\in B} p_X(s)}=\dfrac {\mathbf 1_{x\in B}}{\lvert B\rvert}$$

  - For instance, if $X$ has density of $3$ at *only* one point, say at $x_3$, then the conditional probability that $X=x_3$ when $X=x_3$ will most surely be $1$.
- In other cases it may not even be sensible.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough reply. I guess there is tiny difference between my question and what you wrote and that was conditioning on the value of the density at a single point. I guess I have a little bit of confusion and that is mixing the concept of parametric models with real conditioning. To me it seems rational to say for a discrete RV $X$ where we know $p(X=3)=0.5$ it indeed should be the case that $p(X=3|p(X=3)=0.5)=.5$. I would be happy to know how this can be formalized....

Comment: .... I guess your solution is a bit of a different case where you consider $p(X)$ as an RV (btw thank you for agreeing that $p(X)$ is indeed an RV.) and conditioning on the value that it takes.

Comment: $p_{\small X}(X)$ is a random variable, but $p_{\small X}(3)$ is a constant.  $$p_{\small X\mid p_X(3)=0.5}(3) = \begin{cases}0.5 &:& p_{\small X}(3)=0.5\\\textsf{undefined}&:& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Comment: thank you! That is all I needed, but could you please tell me how can I prove measure theoretically that indeed $p_{X|p_X(3)=0.5}(3)=0.5$ for $X=3$?

Comment: $p_{\small X}(3)=0.5$ is either certainly true or certainly false.  If it is true, then you definitely know what the density at three will be. If it is false, then the conditional measure cannot be defined.